# Trigger semantic release based on pull request title

Tags: github, npm, github-actions, semantic-release

I use `semantic-release` package to trigger semantic release via GitHub Actions. Out of the box it uses `@semantic-release/commit-analyzer` plugin which analyzes the message of each commit in a pull request and determines a version of the release.

Is there a way to set up `semantic-release` to analyze only the title of the pull request which triggered `push` to `main`?

Answer (score 0):

for receive pr title/number on push event u can use

https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/27071#discussioncomment-8008688

```
name: 'Your awesome new GA'

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
jobs:
  pr-number:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      pull-requests: read
    steps:
      - uses: actions/github-script@v7
        id: get_pr_data
        with:
          script: |
              return (
                await github.rest.repos.listPullRequestsAssociatedWithCommit({
                  commit_sha: context.sha,
                  owner: context.repo.owner,
                  repo: context.repo.repo,
                })
              ).data[0];
      - name: Pull Request data
        run: |
          echo '${{ fromJson(steps.get_pr_data.outputs.result).number }}'
          echo '${{ fromJson(steps.get_pr_data.outputs.result).title }}'
```

then combine with ur ci-cd github actions pipeline

```
  release:
    name: Release
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      pull-requests: read
    steps:

      - uses: actions/github-script@v7
        id: get_pr_data
        with:
          script: |
              return (
                await github.rest.repos.listPullRequestsAssociatedWithCommit({
                  commit_sha: context.sha,
                  owner: context.repo.owner,
                  repo: context.repo.repo,
                })
              ).data[0];

      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
          persist-credentials: false

      - name: Setup Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '18'
          registry-url: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'

      - name: Install dependencies and build 
        run: npm ci && npm run build

      - name: Make Release
        run: npx semantic-release
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_TOKEN }}
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
          PULL_REQUEST_TITLE: ${{ fromJson(steps.get_pr_data.outputs.result).title }}
```

and receive it from process.env.PULL_REQUEST_TITLE in ur .releaserc.js

like here

https://github.com/JS-AK/example-automatic-deploy-js-app-to-npm/blob/master/.releaserc.js

```
const ref = process.env.GITHUB_REF;
```